how to solve the problem of multiple elements at position : absolute when animating transtionGroup, or stretching the parent element
Is it possible to make it so that at position-absolute in class .prod-leave-active grid elements do not move to the beginning of the parent element? This happens when transitioning or applying filters, when elements should disappear en masse using transitionGroup .
I tried an alternative, and decided to set a delay for the
.prod-enter-active
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s

and remove posotion : absolute
.prod-leave-active
    transition: all 0.3s ease
    //position : absolute 

but in this case, when between the departure and arrival of elements, in these 0.3 seconds in dom there are both old and invisible new elements, thus lengthening the parent container.
<template>
    <div id="Products">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-bar">
                <ProductsSortPanel
                @update-sort="updateSort"
                @update-grid="updateGrid"
                :category="category"
                ></ProductsSortPanel>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                <FilterGrid
                @getFilterBy="getFilterBy"
                :filter="filter"
                :categories="categories"
                :attributes="attributes"
                ></FilterGrid>
            <div class="products-grid">
                <div 
                :class="gridType == 'columns' ? 'grid-columns' : 'grid-rows'"
                class="products-items">
                
                        <TransitionGroup
                        name="prod"
                        >
                            <ProductCard
                            :style='{animationDelay : `${0.05 * index}s`}'
                            v-for="(product, index) in products.data"
                            class="product-card"
                            :product="product"
                            :key="product.id" 
                            :gridType="gridType"
                            />
                        </TransitionGroup>
    
                </div>
                <ProductPagination 
                :filterBy="filterBy"
                :products="products"></ProductPagination>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { router, Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import ProductPagination from './ProductsPagination.vue'
import ProductsSortPanel from './ProductsSortPanel.vue';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard.vue'
import FilterGrid from '../Filter/FilterGrid.vue'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                filterBy: {},
                buttonShow : false,
                styles: this.$page.props.styles,
                windowTop: null,
                gridType: 'columns',
            }
        },
        components: {
            ProductPagination,
            ProductsSortPanel, 
            ProductCard,
            FilterGrid,
        },
        props: {
                category: Object,
                products: Array,
                filter: Object,
                attributes: Array,
        },
        methods: {
            onScroll(e) {
                this.windowTop = window.top.scrollY 
            },
            updateGrid(data) {
                this.gridType = data
            },
            updateSort(data) {
                this.filterBy.sortBy = data
            },
            getFilterBy(filterBy) {
                this.filterBy = filterBy
            },
        },
        watch: {
            filterBy: {
                handler() {
                    router.visit(`/category/${this.category.id}` , {
                        method: 'get',
                        data: this.filterBy,
                        preserveState: true ,
                        preserveScroll: true ,
                    })
                },
                deep: true,
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
        }, 
        beforeDestroy() {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll)
        },
    }
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
#Products
    display: flex
    width: 100%
    justify-content: center
    padding: 0px 30px
    padding-bottom: 50px
    .content
        width: 100%
        display: flex
        flex-direction: column
        max-width: 1400px
        .content-bar
            width: 100%
        .content-main
            justify-content: space-between
            display: flex
            width: 100%
            gap: 30px
            .products-grid
                display: flex
                flex-direction: column
                gap: 50px
                max-width: calc(100% - 250px - 30px)
                width: 100%
                align-items: center
                .products-items
                    justify-content: space-between
                    display: grid
                    width: 100%
                    margin-bottom: 30px
                    position: relative 

.grid-columns
    justify-content: space-between
    display: grid
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 250px)
    row-gap: 5%

.grid-rows
    display: grid
    grid-template-columns: 1fr
    gap: 10px
    width: 100%
    min-width: 100%

.prod-move
    transition: all 0.3s ease
.prod-enter-active
    transition: all 0.3s ease 
.prod-leave-active
    transition: all 0.3s ease
    position: absolute
.prod-enter-from, .prod-leave-to
    opacity: 0
    transform: translateY(20px)
.prod-enter-to, .prod-leave-from
    opacity: 1
    transform: translateY(0px)

</style>

